# Querying and paginating by a user-defined date in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

This seems like a relatively common use-case but I can't find any slam-dunk answer.  I would like the ability to paginate my results, sorted by a date that is both user-defined and can be modified by the user at any time.

I understand I can add the date to the sort key and delete/re-add the document should the user update the date, or use a secondary index, but neither of these options seem great.

Are there any other options?

Comment: There are no other options if you want it efficient

Answer (score 0):

Why do neither of those options seem great? Can you elaborate some more?

You want to sort based on the timestamp, as we know DynamoDB sorts items based on a Sort Key. For that reason, to fit your use-case needs you would need to use timestamp as the sort key. If your base table is already using something else as a sort-key then you can create an index, which will allow you to define it.

When you change the key of an indexed item, in this case when the user modifies the timestamp value, DynamoDB handles the underlying delete and write for you. All you need to think about is the update.

Comment: I was under the impression that if I structured my schema properly I could avoid a secondary index which would incur added costs.  Adding a non-static date to my sort key seems a little messy, I’d have to track if the user updates the date, delete/re-add the document, replace that document in the local store, etc.  It’s not ideal so I assumed there would be another option, but guess I’m wrong!

Comment: @Steve you only have to delete & re-add the document if the date is the sort key of the table.  If it's the sort key in an index, DDB will simply update the index.  Also local secondary index don't cost any extra, only Global secondary indexes have an added cost.